# Jquery With Button Onclick not display window

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

sorry for my English..I'm very new with javascript...

I want my Jquery code to open a Window,

Here is my code in javascript, Html and Css,

```js
function layer_show_3()
{
 $('#layerPreview-3').attr("style", "top:0px; height:"+$(document).height()+"px; width:"+$(window).width()+"px; display:inline;");
 
 
 var posTop=(($(window).height()/2)-(500/2))+$(document).scrollTop();
 if(posTop<0)
  posTop=0;
 $('#layerPreviewContent-3').attr("style", "top:"+posTop+"px;");
 
 $('#layerPreviewContent-3').show(600);
}


function layer_close_3()
{
 $('#layerPreviewContent-3').hide(300);
 $('#layerPreview-3').hide();
}
```

```css
.kaufen {

 
   float: right;
   width: 45%;
   background-color:  #cccccc;
   padding-right: 10%;
   padding-bottom: 1%;
   margin-left: 3%;
   margin-top: 11%;
   padding-top: 1%;

}
.tittle-kaufen  {margin-left: 15%; font-weight: bold; width: 100%;   float: left; }
.preis {margin-left: 4%; font-weight: bold;  margin-top: 5%; float: left; }
.piece {float: right; font-weight: bold; padding-top: 20%; margin-right: 55%;  }

.quantity {
   float: left;
   margin-top: 5%;
   background-color: #eee;
   position: relative;
   width: 18%;
   overflow: hidden;
   margin-left: 3%;
   border: 1px solid #b3b3b3;
   margin-left: 9%;
}
.quantity input {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 5%;
  padding: 0;
  float: right;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  background-color:  #d9d9d9;
}
.quantity input.qty {
   position: relative;
   border: 0;
   width: 100%;
   padding: 0.625rem 1.5625rem 0.625rem 0.625rem;
   text-align: center;
   font-weight: 400; 
   font-size: 15px;
   border-radius: 0;
   background-clip: padding-box
 }
 .quantity .minus, .quantity .plus {
    line-height: 0;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-background-size: 0.375rem 1.875rem;
    -moz-background-size: 0.375rem 1.875rem;
    color: black;
   font-size: 1.25rem;
   position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  border: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 33%;
  z-index: 3
}
.quantity .minus:hover, .quantity .plus:hover {background-color: #dad8da}
.quantity .minus {bottom: 0}
.button_wrap {

    float: right;
    min-width: 75%;
    background-color: transparent;
    
    background-position-x: 0%;
    background-position-y: 0%;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-image: none;
    background-size: auto;
    background-origin: padding-box;
    background-clip: border-box;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color: #111;
    margin-right: 1%;
    padding-right: 1%;
 }
 .button_wrap_buttom {margin-top: 15%; margin-left: 6%; color: white; background-color:  #b3b3b3; padding: 3%;}
 .button_wrap_buttom:hover {background-color: #666666; }
 .form-basket {

  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0 none;
  font-size: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #111;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 18px;
 }
 .addtobasket-container {

  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0 none;
  font-size: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #111;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 18px;
 }

  /*      ***** Anfang    Fenster 1 producut **** */

 #layerPreview-3  {position:absolute;z-index:1;display:none;top: 0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%;background-color:#fff; 
     background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
 }
 #layerPreviewContent-3{position:absolute;z-index:1;display:none;background-color:#dedee0; margin-top: 0px;left:50%;
    width:30%;
    margin-left:-250px;
    height:40%;
                
                -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.6);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.6);
                box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.6);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ekko-lightbox/5.2.0/ekko-lightbox.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ekko-lightbox/5.2.0/ekko-lightbox.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/elevatezoom/3.0.8/jquery.elevatezoom.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">

  
  <div class="kaufen">

    <form class="form-basket" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <fieldset class="addtobasket-container">    
  
            <span class="tittle-kaufen">Rucksack aus Hanf Gelbe mit Zwei Riemen</span>
 
            <span class="preis"> Preis 40 &euro; </span>

            <span class="piece">Stück</span>
  
           <div class="quantity">

                           
                      <input type="button" value="+" class="plus">
                      <input type="number" step="1" max="99" min="1" value="1" title="Qty" class="qty" size="4">
                      <input type="button" value="-" class="minus">
           </div>
           <div class="button_wrap"  >
                 <button class="button_wrap_buttom" type="buttom"  onclick='layer_show_3();' ><span>Zum warenkorb hinzufügen</span></button>
           </div> 
         </fieldset> 
      </form>      
                        <!-- En el momento que se pulse sobre la capa transparente se cerrara -->
                   <div id="layerPreview-3" > </div>
                   <div id='layerPreviewContent-3'>
                       <!-- Mostramos el texto de cerrar para poder cerrar la ventana -->
                      <div id="tittel-text">Rucksack aus Hanf Gelbe <span id="closse-text"  onclick="layer_close-3();">Schließen</span></div>
                      <div  id="bild-text"><img  alt=""  src="photo/113.jpg"></div>
                        <div id="text-pruduct">
                        <p>Verfügbarkeit: <b>eine Menge</b></p>
                        <p>Zustellung innerhalb von: <b>1-2 Tage</b></p>
                         
                      </div>
                   </div>     

    </div>
  </div>
```

My Problem is when clicking the Botton **Zum warenkorb hinzufügen** nothing displays, when it should open a window..

[Here is the JSFiddle Link for the code](https://jsfiddle.net/ichder/jny73pdx/1/)

Can someone please help me and explain with easy Words what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I think it will be better if you had this sample code on code pen or any other online editor so that you can share the link which will make it easy for someone like me that wants to help you out with this blocker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with how are you trying to handle an `onclick` event on a button, without taking into consideration that this button is a part of a `form`

In simple words, whenever a `button` is pressed inside of a form it tries to `submit` that form via `html` `post` request if not declared otherwise.

So if you want this to work you can do something like this.

Change this

```
<button class="button_wrap_buttom" type="buttom"  onclick='layer_show_3();' ><span>Zum warenkorb hinzufügen</span></button>
```

to

```
<button class="button_wrap_buttom" type="buttom"  onclick='layer_show_3(event);' ><span>Zum warenkorb hinzufügen</span></button>
```

with `event` being passed as `parameter` to `layer_show_3` function.

Change your function declaration to

```
function layer_show_3(event) { ... }
```

and add this line at starting of the function

```
event.preventDefault();
```

this will override the default functionality of a button inside of a form.